# Error when using the latest version of typescript and eslint

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

When I run `eslint .` I get an error:

```
Error: .eslintrc.js » eslint-config-standard-with-typescript:
    Configuration for rule "@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands" is invalid:
    Value {"skipCompoundAssignments":false} should NOT have additional properties.
```

I disabled the "@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands" rule in the configuration:

```
rules: {
  ...
  '@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands': 'off',
}
```

but it doesn't work, I get the same error.

What's the problem?

packages versions:

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.4.1",
"eslint": "^8.48.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
"eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^39.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
"eslint-plugin-n": "^16.0.2",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
"typescript": "^5.2.2",
```

node v14.18.2

npm v6.14.15

**UPD**

After updating "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin" to version 6.4.1, a new error appeared:

```
/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/scope-manager/dist/referencer/ClassVisitor.js:123
        withMethodDecorators ||=
                             ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
```

Comment: This is likely due to the mismatch of versions. You still use v5 for `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` (there is a v6)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler after updating "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin" to version 6.4.1, a new error appeared (look at the end of the question)

Comment: Which node version are you running ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler After upgrading Node from version 14 to 18 everything works, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The support for the `||=` operator has landed in node v15.

So this issue is expected in v14 and can be fixed with a later version (15+)